# ViewPager jumps half the page when switching to next page

Tags: android, android-webview, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I'm using a `ViewPager` with android 3.+ to create a series of articles. On each separate page, I have a `scrollView` which contains the whole article, plus images if there so happens to be one in the feed, all contained within a `webView`.

I've ran into a problem where upon flinging to the next page, the `scrollView` or `webView`, I'm not really sure,  will scroll down half the page without you doing anything.  When this happens once, it continues to happen on each following page.

Any ideas?

** EDIT **

Answer:
[Disable selectable links within WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314309/disable-selectable-links-within-webview)

Answer (score 1):

pseudocode:

```
@Override
onPageSwitch() {
    contentView.setScroll(0);
```

Something like this perhaps as a workaround?

Comment: Tried something similar to that effect. It works, however, the page still firstly jumps down a bit, then scrolls back up to the top from the .setScroll(0).  Looking more into it, it looks as if the links in the webView are being focused, which is causing the page to jump down.  Know of any way to make them not focusable?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but try checking this out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html